# getting an error "Trying to get property of non-object" in phpunit 5.4

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit, ecomdev-phpunit

I am trying to execute the following script in linux(centos 6.6) command prompt, but i am getting an error Trying to get property of non-object.  I am using php version 5.6 and phpunit 5.4.
This is the source file ....

```
    protected function getTenants()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tenant');
        $this->db->where('status',1);
        $rs=$this->db->get();
        return $rs->result();
    }
    public function getInactiveTenants()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tenant');
        $this->db->where('status',0);
        $rs=$this->db->get();
        return $rs->result();
    }
    public function getTenant($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tenant');
        $this->db->where('tenant_id',$id);
        $rs=$this->db->get();
        return $rs->row();
    }
    public function updateTenant($options = array()){
        extract($options);
        //print_r($options);exit;
        $this->db->set ( 'mobile_num', $mobile_num );
        $this->db->set ( 'email', $email );
        $this->db->set ( 'name', $name );
        $this->db->set ( 'phone_num', $phone_num );
        $this->db->set ( 'description', $description );
        $this->db->set ( 'address', $address );
        $this->db->set ( 'city', $city );
        $this->db->set ( 'state', $state );
        $this->db->set ( 'country', $country );
        $this->db->set ( 'created_by', $this->phpsession->get('sess_user_id'));
        $this->db->where('tenant_id',$tenant_id);
        $this->db->update ( "tenant" );
        return 1;
    }
```

This is the file which i used to run to test the above file

```
class Tenant_modelTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public  $CI;


    public function testGetTenants() {
        $this->CI->load->model('tenant_model');
        $posts = $this->CI->tenant_model->getTenants();
        $this->assertEquals($rs->result(), $posts);
    }

    public function testGetInactiveTenants(){
        $this->CI->load->model('tenant_model');
                $results = $this->CI->tenant_model->getInactiveTenants();
                $this->assertEquals($rs->result(), $results);
    }

    public function testGetTenant(){
        $this->CI->load->model('tenant_model');
                $results = $this->CI->tenant_model->getTenants($id);
                $this->assertEquals($rs->result(), $results);
    }

    public function testUpdateTenant(){
        $this->CI->load->model('tenant_model');
                $results = $this->CI->tenant_model->updateTenants($options = array());
                $this->assertEquals(1, $results);

    }
}
```

error:

```
1) Tenant_modelTest::testGetTenants Trying to get property of non-object 
/var/www/html/cloudscheduler/application/tests/tenant_modelTest.php:12 
ERRORS! Tests: 4, Assertions: 0, Errors: 4
```

Can someone please help me on this...

Comment: Please add also error log to your question.

Comment: 1) Tenant_modelTest::testGetTenants
Trying to get property of non-object
/var/www/html/cloudscheduler/application/tests/tenant_modelTest.php:12  ERRORS! Tests: 4, Assertions: 0, Errors: 4.

Comment: Just a guess, but the first object in `testGetTenants()` is `$CI`. Where/how does this get instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the `$CI` object:

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
}
```

Comment: when i ran my script after adding the above piece of code ....getting the error as....

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_instance() in /var/www/html/cloudscheduler/application/tests/project_modelTest.php

Comment: You're not following CI folder structure conventions: controllers go in `application/controllers`, models in `application/models`, external libraries go in `application/libraries`. Controllers must extend `CI_Controller`, models must extend `CI_Model`. Running things from a `tests` folder inside application won't work.